# How do I use the STM32g4xx_HAL_Driver HAL library to read out the sensor data with i2c?

Tags: c, stm32, hal, stm32cubeide

I made a custom MCU Board based on the STM32G431 and try to read the register of a MPU6050. But i cant make the HAL_I2C_Mem_Read working. This is the function i am trying to use:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint16_t MemAddress, uint16_t MemAddSize, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

And i configured it to:

```
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c3, 0x68, 0x0D, 8, &Buffer, 1, 10000);
```

What am i missing?

This is the part to control if it works. I toggle a red and a green LED, depending if it returns HAL_OK or not.

```
status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c3, 0x68, 0x0D, 0x2, &Buffer, 1, 10000);
/*if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) == HAL_OK)*/
if (status == HAL_OK)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(200);

  }

/*if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) != HAL_OK)*/
if (status != HAL_OK)
      {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(200);

      }
```

And this is the MCU+Sensor+LED build:
[image: STM32G431 Custom made Board]

Answer (score 0):

I think `uint16_t MemAddSize` must be `I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT` (0x1) or `I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT`(0x2) not `8` in your code.
P/S: to be sure, did you use stm32Cube and config it correctly? Did you choose and plug the correct pin? And don't forget to check your hardware, maybe some nets are not connected or the i2c bus is affected by noise. I suggest you use a logic analyzer to debug protocol like that.
Be an electrical engineer is painful. Good luck my friend.

Comment: Thx for your help. I used STM32CubeMX for the first configuration. Then i edited the main.c in STM32CubeIDE. First with simple LED turning on and off, so the pins should work. But now as a next step I try to read a sensor. I dont use a Logic Analyzer, just a green and red LED wich are connected to the HAL_OK statement (Code in the post above). The step from Arduino to custom made MCU is pretty tough ^^. Do you have another idea? 0x1 and 0x2 dont work either.

Comment: The code seems to be not a problem. It's really hard to guest. I find some projects making the DIY logic analyzer with Arduino like [here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/vincenzo-g/diy-logic-analyzer-f61ee5) or [here](https://www.element14.com/community/people/jancumps/blog/2015/03/13/make-a-logic-analyzer-from-your-dev-kit-part-1-arduino-uno). Let's try to use one and post the signal result so that I can analyze it easier.

Comment: I would like to do that but the logic analyzer does not work... another problem ^^

Comment: I figured out how to use the logic analyzer but unfortunately the I2C seems to be pretty dead. No signal i could record.